# Selecting random rows from table with sqlalchemy gives not random results

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have, on a pgsql backend, a table and an (allegedly) random access version of it:

```py
class Topic(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
    question_id = db.Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), db.ForeignKey("question.id"))
    topic = db.Column(Enum(QuestionTopicsChoices))


# Create an alias for Topic that uses BERNOULLI sampling method
Topic_rnd = db.aliased(Topic, tablesample(Topic, func.bernoulli(2.5), 10))
```

I'd expect, then, that these two queries return with different results:

```py
topics_linear = Topic.query.filter_by(topic='emotion').all()
topics_random = Topic_rnd.query.filter_by(topic='emotion').all()
```

but they return the records in the same order. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: [`tablesample`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-FROM) doesn't order the rows in any way. In both cases you're getting them in the order they were *retrieved*, which doesn't necessarily correspond to the order they are stored or anything you can or should predict. Same results in the same order from both of these would mean that given that seed of `10` the 2.5% chance is enough for sampler to hit all records with `topic='emotion'`. The order of records might change for either of these at some point. How many rows and different topics you have? How many unique?

Comment: @zegarek, I am making a test to understand how this works. Right now I had ~10 unique rows. How many should I have and with which parameters to be able to see a difference? Edit: even if I generate 10000 rows, I get still the same results :-/